# не могу удалить файл из репозитория. Нет кнопки удалить

Tags: github

[image: В меню три точки нет кнопки удалить]
Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста не могу удалить файл из репозитория. Нет кнопки удалить

Comment: А ты когда текстовый файл на компьютере хочешь удалить, тоже это из текстового редактора пытаешься сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Там внизу в этом меню, которое есть на скриншоте, есть кнопка `Delete file`:

[image: Кнопка "Delete file"]

Просто нужно прокрутить чуть-чуть вниз.

Answer (score 1):

Просто прокрутите чуть чуть вниз и увидите Delete File. (и не забудьте прописать `git pull` в проекте)
А вообще если файл не должен был попадать в удалённый репозиторий, то добавьте его в .gitignore.
Если уже отправили ненужный файл в удалённый репозиторий то есть два способа его удалить через git команды:

1. c помощью команды `git rm путь_до_файл`, затем `git commit -m "подпись коммита"`, и `git push` для отправки на удалённый репозиторий.
2. Просто удаляете его из проекта, затем `git add .`, дальше `git commit -m "подпись коммита"` и `git push --force`